# Project 2007 to 2010 provision failed

Tags: error, migration, project-server

I'm trying to migrate a Project Server instance from 2007 to 2010. The project server migration SQL Server Script does not give any issues from the output. Executing the `stsadm -o addcontentdb` command completes successfully with errors (These are manually written due to client remote software):

> - V2VFeatureActivation2UpgradeSiteAction.Upgrade Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation at
>     Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.CheckPermissions(SPBasePermissions
>     permissionMask)
> - Template MPS#0: SPWeb ID=7a12aeae-f196-4e3a-8b35-1b9a57e11059 could not be access in SPSite ID=67c3cf0a-3eb0-4b3b-9db4-fe36bd6f7edf due to
>     exception. Skipping this spweb for template upgrade. Exception:
>     System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied

The problem that I'm having is Provisioning the Project Web Access Site--Always fails.

Some ULS logs point to workflow lookuptables, and invalid workflow phase or custom field UID? Other ULS logs point to "The enterprise project type sample proposal references a Project Detail Page that was not found in the SharePoint configuration database"

I've followed the Project Server migration path from 2007 to 2010 perfectly. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

- Added install account as DBO to the Draft/Published/Archive/Reporting databases
- Added install account as DBO to the content database
- Added install account as site collection admin after mounting
- Changing `"PWAURL" and "MSPWAPROJUID"` property to NULL according to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brismith/archive/2010/05/18/project-server-2010-my-pwa-site-thinks-it-is-a-workspace-site-revisited.aspx)

I used to have it at least load to the front page, but default.aspx does not load. **I *can* get to the /_layouts/settings.aspx**, but provisioning in Project Service Application will always fail. Any ideas?

Comment: does anyone have an idea, i am facing the exact same problem and not able to resolve it. Any ideas.... BR
Kashif

Comment: Try creating a new, fresh farm with no configuration, that's how I'm dealing with it.

Comment: appreciate your comment, could you please explain in a bit detail. the matter is in critical state now.. BR
Kashif

Comment: check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I configured this to work:

- Disconnected one of the servers from the farm
- Deleted the PWA instance from the PWA Service Application
- Dismounted the content database
- Created a new farm with a new SharePoint Config database
- Created a new web application with Classic Authentication called "PWA"
- Mounted the database with the "stsadm -o addcontentdb" command
- Created a new PWA Service Application
- Provisioned with the PWA instance with the 4 project databases on the "PWA" web application

Comment: Also want to point out if you are using autospinstaller to install SharePoint, I found that you want JUST the base installation of SharePoint to migrate, nothing more. We ended up installing SharePoint and configuring it without AutoSPInstaller, and that is what did the trick.